# ¿Cómo detectar si un elemento es clickable en mis rspecs?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

**Contexto**: En mi rspec (que usan Ruby y Capybara)

1. Pulso en un enlace para comprobar una acción: añadir una rama a mi aplicación
2. Se abre un ventana modal, donde elijo la rama a añadir y clicko "Submit" para añadirla a mi aplicación.
3. Pulso en el botón de "Save" para guardar el estado de mi aplicación (la aplicación funciona así. Hasta que no pulso "Save" no se guardan esos cambios y si pulsase "Refresh" perdería esos cambios).

**Problema**: Mis rspecs fallan porque intentan pulsar "Save" en la pantalla principal mientras la ventana modal que se usa para añadir una nueva rama a la aplicación aún no ha desaparecido. Es decir, el botón de "Save" existe, pero está detrás de la ventana modal, y por lo tanto no se puede pulsar.

El fallo que vemos es

`[...]Save</button> is not clickable at point (692, 23). Other element would receive the click[...]`

**Sutileza**: Mis tests pasan en mi entorno local, pero a veces fallan al ser ejecutados por nuestro *automation server*. Es decir, son "**flaky tests**" y con la información que tengo sobre el fallo entiendo que esta es la causa del mismo, que se intenta pulsar un botón que todavía no está disponible porque la ventana modal todavía está presente.

**Posibles soluciones**: Primero intentamos jugar con las configuraciones de nuestros "clicks" para asegurarnos de que estamos en "ready state" y que la ventana modal se había cerrado. Al seguir fallando intentamos forzar una espera manual mediante un bucle

```
  while Utilities.element_visible?(:xpath, miElemento)
     sleep(0.5)
  end 
  XYZ.save
```

que de nuevo funciona en un entorno local pero padece "flakiness" en el *automation server*.

Me preguntaba si el siguiente paso no sería hacer un "find" antes del "save" para ver si el botón está disponible (clickable), pero no consigo encontrar en la documentación si [find](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) me da esta sutileza de que el botón exista y sea visible pero no clickable (es decir, que esté tras la ventana modal).

En cualquier caso el `Utilities.element_visible?(:xpath, miElemento)` que ya estamos utilizando ya me debería estar haciendo esta llamada a comprobación mediante una llamada a

```
find(method,element).visible?
```

que ya existe en mi función `element_visible?`.

Lo que me deja casi en la casilla de salida.

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de detectar si un elemento que puede estar tras una ventana modal es **clickable** en mis rspecs?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el método `has_button?` de la siguiente manera `do_something if page.has_button?('.clase_del_boton')` 
Mas información [aquí](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_button%3F-instance_method)